# Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client on OS X Yosemite - CSD library signature verification failed

Tags: vpn, macos

I just updated my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) to latest OS X Yosemite (10.10 (14A389)) and `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client` (3.1.05182) is generating an error while trying to connect:

```
Posture Assessment Failed: CSD library signature verification failed.
```

[Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client VPN User Messages, Release 3.1 - Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect31/user/messages/ac31-vpn-user-msgs.html) states following:

```
CSD library signature verification failed.
Description    The signature of the library could not be verified. This indicates a problem with the CSD library.

Recommended Action    Remove the library from the cache, and try a new connection.
```

Removing library from the cache did *NOT* solve my issue(

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Cisco's [Release Notes for Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client, Release 3.1 - Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect31/release/notes/anyconnect31rn.html#pgfId-262963) version `3.1.05187` should (re)solve this issue, unfortunately I'm still on previous release `3.1.05182`. I'll post my finding as soon as I get to download new build (unless someone will beat me to it ;p).

---

We removed CSD from the configuration and used the latest version of HostScan instead:

```
no csd image disk0:/csd_3.5.841-k9.pkg
csd hostscan image disk0: /anyconnect-win-3.1.05187-k9.pkg
```

Comment: Installed `3.1.05187`, still unable to connect and still getting same error, already opened ticket with Cisco...

Comment: `hostscan` has to be on version 3.1, same as client in order for this to work! as soon as we updated our hostscan to 3.1+, i was able to vpn in without any issues)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as the OP with Cisco AnyConnect version 2.3.2016: installing OS X 10.10 Yosemite broke it. Scrounging up a copy of 3.1.05187 WORKS (kind of) on my Mac.

I said "scrounge" because I couldn't download the correct version from [Cisco's web site](http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=286281272&flowid=72042&softwareid=282364313&release=3.1.05187&relind=AVAILABLE&rellifecycle=&reltype=latest), because I don't have a login there associated with our license, and I couldn't get our local tech folks to understand why I couldn't just install the "MSI" file on my Mac.

Anyway, searching the web for "anyconnect-macosx-i386-3.1.05187-k9.dmg" unearthed a copy from a university web site (not something I like to do, particularly with security software), and behold, it installed and runs!

One wrinkle: unlike the older version, the newer one didn't route DNS lookups through the VPN. When Cisco establishes a VPN connection, it seems they edit "/etc/resolv.conf" to add the VPN's DNS servers. That doesn't work, and there's a warning to that effect in the Apple-generated "resolv.conf" file.

My work-around is to consult what Cisco added and manually add those servers through the Mac OS X Network Preference Pane.

Comment: I really don't understand why Cisco has to make downloading their VPN client software so impossible.  I go through this nonsense with the Hostscan failing to launch every time I upgrade OSX.  Then I have to do something dirty like download a DMG file off a third party website (thanks for the tip, it worked and now I'm back on the VPN).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how to clean your caches:

1. Open `~/Library/Caches` in Finder.
2. From the Menu bar, choose `Edit > Select All`.
3. Drag all of the items to the Trash.
4. From the Macintosh HD, choose `Library > Caches`.
5. Choose `Edit > Select All`, and drag the items to the Trash. You'll be required to type in an administrator’s password.
6. Restart your Mac.

Comment: Cisco's recommended action did not solve my issue(

Comment: `Show/Hide View Options` `⌘J` > `Show Library Folder`

Answer (score -1):

Are you licensed for the mobility client? Look at your Cisco ASA information and see if AnyConnect for Mobile is enabled or disabled.

Comment: VPN was working fine prior to upgrading it to `Yosemite (10.10)`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the unerlying issue is that Yosemite will not load kext (kernel extensions) unless they are signed by an authorized kernel extension developer. However in 10.8 and earlier, kexts could not be signed and signed kexts for 10.9+ will not load in <10.9.

Try this and after that reboot and try again.

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"
```

<sup>To revert do: `sudo nvram -d boot-args`</sup>

Comment: That's not it, as I was able to get it going without messing with my nvram.